# sequelize use instance method after selecting result

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I want to understand how sequelize instance methods works and if its possible to use returned object as instance for further usage. Basically I'm just selecting user by its user name, later I want to compare if password matches and if so - update data. But the error says

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: user_data.validPassword is not a function

and I'm not even close to instance update..

my User model:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        user_name: DataTypes.STRING,
        user_password: DataTypes.STRING,
        user_token: DataTypes.STRING,
        user_alias_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {
        tableName: 'oc_users',
        instanceMethods: {
            generateHash(password) {
                return bcrypt.hash(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8));
            },
            validPassword(password) {
                return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
            }
        }
    });

    return User;
};
```

my method:

```
...
loginAttempt(cookie) {
    return models.User.findOne({
        attributes: ['id', 'user_password', 'user_alias_name'],
        where: {user_name: this.user}
    }).then(user_data => {
        if (!user_data) return 'No matching results for such a user';
        return user_data.validPassword(this.password).then(result => {
            if (result !== true) return 'Invalid password for selected user';
            return this.updateAfterLogin(user_data, cookie);
        })
    })
}

updateAfterLogin(user, cookie) {
    return user.update({
        user_token: cookie
    }).then(()=> {
        return {data: 'updated'};
    })
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of sequelize you're using and probabily you're using Sequelize v4. On Sequelize v4 classMethods and instanceMethods were removed from sequelize.define.

You may check it at oficial docs for more informations:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#config-options

> Removed classMethods and instanceMethods options from sequelize.define. Sequelize models are now ES6 classes. You can set class / instance level methods like this

**Old**

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (model) {...}
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        someMethod: function () { ...}
    }
});
```

**New**

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
});

// Class Method
Model.associate = function (models) {
    ...associate the models
};

// Instance Method
Model.prototype.someMethod = function () {..}
```